# Remove everything inside div but keep children with specific class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to erase everything inside a div but keep a paragraph element with an specific class name.

```
<div class="example-container%>
  <p class="element-iwant-to-keep">
    this is the text of the div that i want to keep.
  </p>

  <ul><li>more text i dont want to keep</li></ul>
  <ul><li>more text i dont want to keep</li></ul>
  <ul><li>more text i dont want to keep</li></ul>
  some more text inside the main div i dont want to keep.
</div>
```

So far i was trying the following but is not working.

```
$(".example-container").each(function(){
    var _noNested = $(this).html();
    var _removedNest = _noNested.replace(/(<p[^>]+?>|<p>|<\/p>)/img, "");   
    $(this).find("element-iwant-to-keep").html(_removedNest).nextAll('p').remove();
});
```

So I want to remove everything inside the div but just keep the first "p" element. Because of the scenario I can't empty the div like

```
$(".example-container").html("");
```

And then append or add the first div again, in this case the challenge is to keep the first div and remove what is left inside the div.

Thank you for your help all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **[make a copy](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)** of the node(s) you want to keep, you can then wipe out all the content of the container and then place the copy(ies) back in.

```js
let copy = $("div.example-container p.element-iwant-to-keep").clone(true); // Get a copy of the node you want to keep
$("div.example-container").html(copy); // Clear out the container and put in the copy
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example-container">
  <p class="element-iwant-to-keep">
    this is the text of the div that i want to keep.
  </p>

  <ul><li>more text i dont want to keep</li></ul>
  <ul><li>more text i dont want to keep</li></ul>
  <ul><li>more text i dont want to keep</li></ul>
  some more text inside the main div i dont want to keep.
</div>
```

Comment: This one is really helpful. I did a little bit of changes but it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. Filter the children and remove all siblings.
2. Filter node type 3 to remove text

```js
$(".example-container").children().filter(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("element-iwant-to-keep")) {
    $(this).remove()//remove siblings
  }
})
$(".example-container").contents().filter(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == 3) {
    $(this).remove()//remove text
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example-container">
  <p class="element-iwant-to-keep">
    this is the text of the div that i want to keep.
  </p>

  <ul>
    <li>more text i dont want to keep</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>more text i dont want to keep</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>more text i dont want to keep</li>
  </ul>
  some more text inside the main div i dont want to keep.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the html of the parent element to be the content you want to keep.

In the following - on the button click (just for this demo purpose) I have grabbed the html of the element to be kept and then reset the html of the parent element with it.

```js
$('.resetDiv').click(function(){
  var element=$('.element-iwant-to-keep').html();
  $('.example-container').html(element)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example-container">
  <p class="element-iwant-to-keep">
    this is the text of the div that i want to keep.
  </p>

  <ul><li>more text i dont want to keep</li></ul>
  <ul><li>more text i dont want to keep</li></ul>
  <ul><li>more text i dont want to keep</li></ul>
  some more text inside the main div i dont want to keep.
</div>
<hr/>
<button type = "button" class="resetDiv">Click me to reset the content of the div</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concise version with caching and chaining. We can use `end()` to go back to a previous state in our chaining call.

> End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and
>   return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

```js
// Store this element in a variable to avoid multiple lookups
$container = $(".example-container");

// Create named functions for clarity
function removeElements() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("element-iwant-to-keep")) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
}

function removeTextNodes() {
  if (this.nodeType === 3) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
}

$container
  .children()
  .filter(removeElements)
  .end()
  .end()
  .contents()
  .filter(removeTextNodes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example-container">
  <p class="element-iwant-to-keep">
    this is the text of the div that i want to keep.
  </p>

  <ul><li>more text i dont want to keep</li></ul>
  <ul><li>more text i dont want to keep</li></ul>
  <ul><li>more text i dont want to keep</li></ul>
  some more text inside the main div i dont want to keep.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try: $(".example-container").not("p").html(""); ?

Comment: Please provide clarification of your answer for people you will find this answer later.